# Do Gods and Goddesses regain their power inside dungeon?

Tags: danmachi

In episode 12, when Hestia walked up to Bell who was battling with the envious adventurer, she was glowing while angrily saying something like "I said stop!" - referring to the battle. Meanwhile, Hermes, overlooking them from a cliff, said that Hestia released her power.

I'm aware of the rule that Gods and Goddesses are not allowed inside dungeon. But at this point, I'm confused whether the Gods and Goddesses regain their power inside dungeons, or they possess it all the time (even outside dungeon) but they just don't use it? I don't mind if the answer contain spoilers.

Comment: I didn't even notice this...

Comment: notice what? the glow in Hestia or what? hehe please complete your comment :)

Comment: ... *this* being the part where, *"Hermes, overlooking them from a cliff, said that Hestia released her power"*. Or in other words, it didn't trigger a reaction enough for me to read into it any more than usual. Kudos to you for picking up on something interesting (well, possibly).

Comment: Never mind, I haven't actually seen episode 12 yet. I only thought I had.

Comment: oh sorry if i spoil you or anything. I'm just really into this anime that i keep thinking about this gods power thing. This is my favorite on going anime this season :)

Comment: Well, that's how I'd read it. Seems like Hestia released her divine power. I guess we'll learn more about that in the coming episodes.

Answer (score 3):

They never lost it. Aside from the rule of them not being allowed in the Dungeon, it is also stated at the beginning of all three forms of the series (anime, manga and LN) that the Deities are not allowed to use their power while they reside in the human world.

Comment: can you give something of proofs?

Comment: so this is super late, I'm afraid, but this comes straight from the first novel, page 21:

>While gods are in Gekai, they can't use their godly powers, called Arkanam. It's a rule they set themselves shortly after arriving.

Most of pages 20-21 explain the arrival of the gods and what that meant for the humans. Gekai is the name of the lower world, where they reside now. Tenaki is the name of the upper world, where they used to reside - and where some still do.

Answer (score 0):

Well the gods sealed their powers on earth and the reason they are not allowed to go in the dungeon is because they are not allowed to unseal their powers which makes them weak, Hestia entered the dungeon as did Hermes but nothing happened yet when Hestia released her power the dungeon that was proven by the mid-levels to be semi/fully sentient saw Hestia as something that needed to be removed, the fact she sealed her powers again is how i think they won, had she left her powers unsealed the dungeon would not have stopped until they were all dead.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.